# How could I achieve design like showin in attach image using grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Here is the code of the gridbox, I have currently.

```css
.service-box-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 2fr);
    gap: 15px;
}

.service-box-container img{
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  height: 460px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="service-box-container">

  <div class="service-box">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" class="" alt="">
      </figure>
  </div>
  
  <div class="service-box">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" class="" alt="">
      </figure>
  </div>
  
  <div class="service-box">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" class="" alt="">
      </figure>
  </div>
  
  <div class="service-box">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" class="" alt="">
      </figure>
  </div>
  
  <div class="service-box">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" class="" alt="">
      </figure>
  </div>
  
  <div class="service-box">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" class="" alt="">
      </figure>
  </div>
  
  <div class="service-box">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" class="" alt="">
      </figure>
  </div>
  
  <div class="service-box">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" class="" alt="">
      </figure>
  </div>
  
  <div class="service-box">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" class="" alt="">
      </figure>
  </div>
  
  <div class="service-box">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" class="" alt="">
      </figure>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```

Design I am looking to acheive:

[image]

I want to show only two items on every even row and 3 items on every odd row using grid css. This should be applicable to any additional rows as well.

Currently it is showing same style on both odd and even row. Here, is the https://jsfiddle.net/fk9y0uhd/3

Comment: Use a 6 column grid

Answer (score -1):

Use grid-row-start and grid-row-end properties same like for column as well grid-col-start and grid-col-end to make this layout. this will help you out
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xBSlwwitD5U&t=867s check. OR use  3 column grid for odd one and 6 column grid for evens.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).